# map files names to mytext to find them easier

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to find a way to map file names to my own name, so I can find them easier.
For example, I have some pages and modals that have a different name than the file, for example:
UserMaterialModal.js is named materials

I want to map UserMaterialModal.js to materials when I search the file materials to suggest userMaterialModal.js.

like:

```
 files: {
'UserMaterialModal.js' => 'materials'
}
```